# Is there a way to switch selection via hotkeys?

Tags: selection-tools, shortcut

Say, I've created just a cube and a cylinder and now the cube is selected. Is there a hotkey that switches selection to the cylinder?

I guess, the order of switching (if there's more than 2 objects) may be different like switching between tabs in a browser: "by usage" and "by creation order", the former being more helpful. Switching between objects would decrease mouse/touchpad usage tremendously. I guess, there's either some "history of selection" object in the Blender core and this is implemented or this is not implementable without changing the core.. but I may be wrong.

The same question may be asked about switching between faces/edges/vertices of one object, but let's start from the switching between objects.

Comment: Usage of Blender like many other 3d programs without mouse may be quite limited..You can use Outliner to select objects clicking on their names, but that won't allow you avoid using mouse. And I don't think there's a "history of selection" - selection like any other action is recorded in the stack of undo options and thus can be accessed from there (and overwritten with newer events too).

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> inverts your selection.

That is, anything currently selected becomes unselected; anything unselected becomes selected.

That will include any cameras and lights you have on the current layer.